# Import from `yarn link` packages not working

Tags: typescript, yarn-v2

I have a package structure as follows

```
-> projectA
-> libA
  ->dist/
     ->index.js
  index.ts
  package.json
```

I compiled the package `libA` using Typescript and then used `yarn link ../libA/dist` in `projectA` to link the library to use.

However when I look in the `node_modeules` in `projectA` I get

```
-> node_modules
  ->dist/
    -> index.js
```

instead of getting the package name `libA`

Now I can

```
import {ExportedName} from "dist"
```

but I want to

```
import {ExportedName} from "libA"
```

How can I set up `yarn link` so that the exports actually have the correct name?